# Complex JSON to Swift

Tags: json, swift

So I am relatively new to JSON and converting it to Swift. I have only dealt with basic JSON with simple data types. Nothing fancy. I also have only dealt with using JSON that I have created.

Now I am trying to use JSON that I have gathered from and API. This JSON has nested objects inside of other objects.

here is the format of the JSON:

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "id": "Info",
        "fields": {
            "Card Name": "Info",
            "Qty": 0,
            "Card Type": "Info",
            "Color": "Info",
            "Card #": "Info",
            "Rarity": "Info",
            "Image": [
                {
                    "id": "Info",
                    "url": "url",
                    "filename": "info",
                    "size": 0,
                    "type": "info",
                    "thumbnails": {
                        "small": {
                            "url": "url",
                            "width": 0,
                            "height": 0
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "url": "url",
                            "width": 0,
                            "height": 0
                        },
                        "full": {
                            "url": "url",
                            "width": 0,
                            "height": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Level": 0,
            "Full Set": 0
        },
        "createdTime": "info"
    }
],
"offset": "info"
}
```

I am not sure if I need to do anything with the "records": portion. Now there are more records within the "records": array.

I don't need all of the information within each record.

I tried doing something like:

```
struct Card {
    let offSet: String
    let cardName: String
}

extension Card: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case offSet
        case cardName
        
        enum FieldKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case cardName = "Card Name"
            }
    }
    
    
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        offSet = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .offSet)
        
        let fieldContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.FieldKeys.self, forKey: .cardName)
        cardName = try fieldContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .cardName)
    }
    
}
```

Every time I try to decode the info into my Swift Struct it just comes up nil. Not sure what I am doing wrong or where to go from here. I haven't dealt with JSON that have "records": setup like this. Not sure if this even matters.

Also a side question in regards to images. Would I just use the url property to display the image? The image files will be PNG. Never dealt with images and JSON before.

Comment: What's your code when this happens? But `records` is an array (possiblity multiple values), when this happens you want which `cardName`? You need to pass that structure. Your code can't guess that the field `CardName` is after Records, it could be anywhere, and after fields.

Comment: Try online tools will generate it faster for you and through practicing you will figure out how to structure it by yourself which is basically to follow the same structure as a response. https://www.json4swift.com/

Comment: Parse with intermediary structs it'd be easier. You can make them private if needed, and add a `lazy var` on the top level `struct` where you'd retrieve the value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larme commented **"Your code can't guess"** - Meaning you need to represent the same structure in code as your JSON provides.

In danger of doing the work for you I've written a very verbose set of `Codable` `struct`'s that pull out all of the data from the JSON you provided.

```
struct Card: Codable {
    var records:[Record]
    var offset:String
}

struct Record: Codable {
    var id:String
    var fields:Fields
    var createdTime:String
}

struct Fields: Codable {
    var name:String
    var quantity:Int
    var type:String
    var color:String
    var number:String
    var rarity:String
    var level:Int
    var fullSet:Int
    var image:[Image]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Card Name"
        case quantity = "Qty"
        case type = "Card Type"
        case color = "Color"
        case number = "Card #"
        case rarity = "Rarity"
        case level = "Level"
        case fullSet = "Full Set"
        case image = "Image"
    }
}

struct Image: Codable {
    var id:String
    var url:String
    var filename:String
    var size:Int
    var type:String
    var thumbnails:Thumbnails
}

struct Thumbnails: Codable {
    var small:Thumbnail
    var large:Thumbnail
    var full:Thumbnail
}

struct Thumbnail: Codable {
    var url:String
    var width:Int
    var height:Int
}
```

I tested the above in a playground by pasting the JSON you provided as a multiline string and using the following to dump the resulting objects.

```
do {
    if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
        let card = try JSONDecoder().decode(Card.self, from: data)
        dump(card)
    }
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to decode \(error)")
}
```

The output of which was:

```
▿ __lldb_expr_21.Card
  ▿ records: 1 element
    ▿ __lldb_expr_21.Record
      - id: "Info"
      ▿ fields: __lldb_expr_21.Fields
        - name: "Info"
        - quantity: 0
        - type: "Info"
        - color: "Info"
        - number: "Info"
        - rarity: "Info"
        - level: 0
        - fullSet: 0
        ▿ image: 1 element
          ▿ __lldb_expr_21.Image
            - id: "Info"
            - url: "url"
            - filename: "info"
            - size: 0
            - type: "info"
            ▿ thumbnails: __lldb_expr_21.Thumbnails
              ▿ small: __lldb_expr_21.Thumbnail
                - url: "url"
                - width: 0
                - height: 0
              ▿ large: __lldb_expr_21.Thumbnail
                - url: "url"
                - width: 0
                - height: 0
              ▿ full: __lldb_expr_21.Thumbnail
                - url: "url"
                - width: 0
                - height: 0
      - createdTime: "info"
  - offset: "info"
```

---

Once you have all the data you could start simplifying things, perhaps an extension to the Card that gets the first records name.

```
extension Card {
    var cardName:String {
        guard let firstRecord = self.records.first else {
            return "Unknown Name"
        }
        return firstRecord.fields.name
    }
}

print(card.cardName) // "Info\n"
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This is a side project I am working on for a hobby, busy life. This is a HUGE help. I was able to take this and use this as a guideline. I found a tutorial to help also. I usually have to see how things work before I fully grasp it. Now I can refine this more, as it turns out, I don't need some of that data. So I can modify to that and now I have a better idea. I will be generating different JSON structures and practicing. 

GREAT STARTING POINT!!!